# Adding the results of multiple alerts that is inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop, alert

My goal with this code is to create a makeshift shopping cart that gives the option to choose from a small selection of items, choose your quantity, get your total, remove items if you want and proceed to "checkout". My issue is, once I get the results of the price by the type of item (via alert), I don't know how to add all of the potential alerts together since it's running in a for loop. Does anyone have an idea on how to do this? I am fairly new to JS and don't know how to proceed. This is also my first question here on stack, so forgive me if it's an odd question.

Here is my code:

```
var item = function(itemName, itemPrice, itemTax) {
  this.products = itemName;
  this.cost = itemPrice;
  this.taxes = itemTax;
  this.total = itemPrice + (itemPrice * itemTax)
}

var list = [];

list[0] = new item("Shoes", 67.99, .075);
list[1] = new item("Coat", 78.99, .075);
list[2] = new item("Book", 9.99, .075);
list[3] = new item("Suitcase", 56.99, .075);

function theStore() {
  var greeting = prompt("Welcome to xxxxxxxx! Do you want to begin shopping?");



  while (greeting === "Yes")
  {

      for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) 
      {
        var j = list[i];
        var adding = prompt("The " + j.products + " cost " + j.cost + ". Would you like to add it to your cart?")
        if (adding === "Yes")
        {
          var addingMore = prompt("How much do you want?")
          if (addingMore < 1)
          {
            alert("This item was not added to your cart.") 
          }

          else
          {
            alert(addingMore + " of " + j.products +" has been added to your cart." + " Your total for this kind of item is " + addingMore * (j.cost) + ".")
          }

      }
      else
      {
        alert(j.products + " was not added to your cart.")
      }
    }

    greeting = prompt("Do you want to continue shopping? Yes or No");


  }
}

theStore()
```

Ideally, when the user prompts "No" (line 47) I want to show them the total of all the items.

Any help/tips/advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a variable totalAmount outside the loop, and add to it as the user adds things to the cart. Then when the user hits no alert the total Amount.

I added a subtotal variable that is calculated by when the user selects the quantity of items. The subtotal is the added to the variable totalAmount which is alerted at the end.

```
var item = function(itemName, itemPrice, itemTax) {
  this.products = itemName;
  this.cost = itemPrice;
  this.taxes = itemTax;
  this.total = itemPrice + (itemPrice * itemTax)
}

var list = [];
var totalAmount = 0;

list[0] = new item("Shoes", 67.99, .075);
list[1] = new item("Coat", 78.99, .075);
list[2] = new item("Book", 9.99, .075);
list[3] = new item("Suitcase", 56.99, .075);

function theStore() {
  var greeting = prompt("Welcome to xxxxxxxx! Do you want to begin shopping?");



  while (greeting === "Yes")
  {

      for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) 
      {
        var j = list[i];
        var adding = prompt("The " + j.products + " cost " + j.cost + ". Would you like to add it to your cart?")
        if (adding === "Yes")
        {
          var addingMore = prompt("How much do you want?")
          if (addingMore < 1)
          {
            alert("This item was not added to your cart.") 
          }

          else
          {
            var subTotal = addingMore * (j.cost);
            totalAmount += subTotal;
            alert(addingMore + " of " + j.products +" has been added to your cart." + " Your total for this kind of item is " + subTotal.toString() + ".")
          }

      }
      else
      {
        alert(j.products + " was not added to your cart.")
      }
    }

    greeting = prompt("Do you want to continue shopping? Yes or No");

    if(greeting === "No"){
        alert("Your Total Amount is: " + totalAmount);
    }

  }
}

theStore()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var item = function(itemName, itemPrice, itemTax) {
  this.products = itemName;
  this.cost = itemPrice;
  this.taxes = itemTax;
  this.total = itemPrice + (itemPrice * itemTax)
}

var list = [];

list[0] = new item("Shoes", 67.99, .075);
list[1] = new item("Coat", 78.99, .075);
list[2] = new item("Book", 9.99, .075);
list[3] = new item("Suitcase", 56.99, .075);

    var selected_items = [];

    function theStore() {
      var greeting = confirm("Welcome to xxxxxxxx! Do you want to begin shopping?");



      while (greeting)
      {

          for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) 
          {
            var j = list[i];
            var adding = confirm("The " + j.products + " cost " + j.cost + ". Would you like to add it to your cart?")
            if (adding)
            {
              var addingMore = prompt("How much do you want?")
              if (addingMore < 1)
              {
                alert("This item was not added to your cart.") 
              }

              else
              {
                alert(addingMore + " of " + j.products +" has been added to your cart." + " Your total for this kind of item is " + addingMore * (j.cost) + ".");
    j.quantity = addingMore;              // Add user selected quantity to object

    j.total_cost = addingMore * (j.cost); // Add cost if user selected quantity to object

    selected_items.push(j);               // Let's store it in array.
              }

          }
          else
          {
            alert(j.products + " was not added to your cart.")
          }
        }

        greeting = confirm("Do you want to continue shopping? Yes or No");

      return selected_items;
      }
    }

    // theStore() Stored array can be utilised for processing.
    console.log(theStore());
```